How to manually boot from grub after pressing Esc
I know there are somwehat similar topics.
I'm asking purely for pedagogical reasons/ my curiosity.
I've been trying to get GUI on WSL and android working.
So, for practice and because it's a useful skill, I'm wondering how would one manually boot from the Grub shell.
Like a list of steps and command. Other people offered simple and short solutions aimed at recovery, But I want the nity gritty and no shortcuts.
Like I don't want to install/update/repair grub or repair some system file and reboot.
I want to be able to manually do all the commands that get me from terminal to "acceptable" session.
I'm using arch and have become quite familiar with the installation.
I tried to manual boot from arch install for hours but it didn't work.
What I want is basically how to manually write every command that grub does so I can start systemd, activate the display, start x, go to a login manager and login to i3.
Note xfce4-session is a cheap solution that works too easily, I want something general enough to be applicable to others.
Like I got it working on WSL but couldn't do other thing.
I just like arch linux and learning how the system work.
Thank you in advance for your time.
I mainly boot to Sddm and then i3. But gdm3 is acceptable too.

GRUB is only concerned about loading the kernel and the initramfs file(s), nothing else. Once the kernel is loaded and started, GRUB's job is done and it gets overwritten in RAM. The rest of the boot is managed by scripts in initramfs and/or the init subsystem (which might be systemd, classic SysVinit, or something else).
GRUB modules
If Secure Boot is in effect, the grubx64.efi binary that was loaded by the UEFI firmware must already contain all the GRUB modules as built-in, so you won't need to use any insmod commands; proceed directly to Finding the kernel and initramfs.
Otherwise, since you can use the keyboard and see things on the screen, I assume the GRUB core image already contains as built-ins:

the module(s) needed for keyboard and display (at_keyboard.mod and appropriate video_*.mod driver), or for serial port if you don't have a display
if your system firmware doesn't provide adequate support for reading the filesystem that holds your /boot/grub[2] directory, the necessary modules for direct disk controller support (maybe ahci.mod, pata.mod or others) and its dependencies
the partition table driver for the disk that contains the filesystem that holds your /boot/grub[2] directory (usually part_msdos.mod or part_gpt.mod)
the filesystem driver for the filesystem containing your /boot/grub[2] directory, and the dependencies for it
if your /boot/grub[2] is on a software RAID, encrypted, or LVM partition, the modules required for those functionalities

If these modules aren't already available, you are stuck because you would need more modules to access the /boot/grub[2] directory that contains the GRUB modules you would need (a "Catch-22" situation). This would be a GRUB core image preparation error; to fix it, you'll need to re-run grub-install, specifying the missing modules with the --modules= option.
If the above-mentioned modules don't already cover the disk+partition+filesystem you're keeping your kernel and initramfs files in, now is the time to load them too. And unless you are in GRUB rescue mode, normal.mod should already be loaded - and it will take care of loading any further command, filesystem and cryptography modules automatically from this point.
Finding the kernel and initramfs
(If you know you'll need to do something special in order to access the filesystem that contains your kernel and initramfs files, this is the time to do it. That covers things like unlocking disk encryption, detecting software RAID or LVM, or setting up access to disk image files.)
Now you can use GRUB commands to identify your filesystems and locate your kernel and initramfs. The autogenerated configuration file of modern versions of GRUB does this by using the search command to find the filesystem by its UUID. But as a human, you might prefer using the ls command with TAB completion instead:

type ls (TAB to list all disks detected by GRUB
type e.g. ls(hd0,TAB to list all partitions on disk (hd0)
if e.g. partition (hd0,gpt1) contains a filesystem recognized by GRUB, type ls(hd0,gpt1)/ to list the contents of the root directory of that filesystem.

Your goal at this point is to figure out the GRUB-style (disk,partition)/path/filename paths to your kernel and initramfs files. For example, if your root filesystem is at (hd0,gpt2) and your /boot/ directory is included in the root filesystem (= not as a separate filesystem), the paths might look like this:

kernel: (hd0,gpt2)/boot/vmlinuz-<kernel version>
initramfs: (hd0,gpt2)/boot/initramfs-<kernel version>

You can minimize the need of typing by setting the GRUB variable root= to indicate the filesystem to use, for example:
set root=(hd0,gpt2)

Then the remaining three GRUB command lines will be:
linux /boot/vmlinuz-<kernel version> <kernel boot parameters>
initrd /boot/initramfs-<kernel version>
boot

(In UEFI systems, you might need to replace linux with linuxefi in some cases.)
Kernel boot parameters (a.k.a. kernel command line)
If you have built a custom kernel that has a default root filesystem path set to match your actual root filesystem, you might not need any kernel boot parameters at all. But you might still want to specify the root filesystem using the root= kernel boot parameter: that makes it easier to change if you change your system configuration, for example.
Your initramfs generator (I think Arch uses mkinitcpio by default) determines the contents of the initramfs file, and any boot parameters the commands and scripts within it might honor. With mkinitcpio, you might want to add the break keyword to stop the scripted boot process within initramfs, and give you a shell you can use to examine the status of the system in this very early phase.
Once the GRUB command boot is issued, GRUB will start the kernel it loaded into RAM earlier with the linux (or linuxefi) command. From that point onwards, GRUB's work is done and the kernel will determine on its own what happens next.
Next steps
On BIOS systems, the kernel will switch the system from 16-bit DOS compatibility mode to true 64- or 32-bit mode, and on UEFI systems, it will make a firmware call to exit UEFI boot services. Either of these actions will make it impossible for GRUB to continue: on UEFI systems, it ends access to UEFI firmware boot services which UEFI version of GRUB must rely on to work, and on BIOS systems, the transition out of 16-bit DOS compatibility mode switches the processor to a completely different fundamental mode than the mode BIOS version of GRUB must be built for.
Once the kernel has initialized itself, it will execute whatever is placed as /init in the initramfs file. If that is not available, the kernel will attempt to run /sbin/init, /etc/init, /bin/init and ultimately /bin/sh, in this order. If your system is using systemd, the init will probably be a minimal version of systemd, with a specialized configuration for in-initramfs use. See man 7 bootup and its BOOTUP IN THE INITRD chapter for more details, and man 1 systemd's KERNEL COMMAND LINE chapter for options you can use to influence this part of the boot process.

If you want to start a shell as early as possible when using systemd-based initramfs, you could supply the boot parameter rd.systemd.unit=emergency.target. This might result a more early shell access than when using the break boot parameter.
If you want to focus on the post-initramfs boot process, you could supply the boot parameter init=/bin/bash. It will typically cause the boot process to end as soon as the real root filesystem is mounted. To continue the boot process from there, you would need a command like exec /sbin/init. Another way to interrupt the systemd boot process just after initramfs would be to use the systemd.unit=emergency.target boot parameter (without the rd. prefix).

After booting with init=/bin/bash, you could in principle manually remount the root filesystem in read/write mode, mount any other necessary filesystems, configure network parameters, and then start /usr/sbin/gdm &. However, in practice, it might be configured for use with systemd environment and complain if certain background services, e.g. the system D-Bus, are not available. I don't know Arch well enough to give you an exact list of things you would need to start.

You need to prefix the the file paths with / (assuming the files are directly under root), e.g. linux /vmlinuz-linux. While you can more or less set the GRUB variable root= to the common part of the paths, when the variable is not (just) a drive (e.g. hd0,gpt2), / cannot be used to denote it. Instead you'll need to use $root (e.g. linux $root/vmlinuz-linux, assuming the variable consists of no trailing /).

@TomYan Duh! My mistake - edited to what I was originally thinking. Your comment actually covers a slightly different but equally valid (and maybe more efficient) way to do it.
